# How to upgrade my realm db in android

Tags: android, realm

In my android project, we are using Realm db version `0.87.4`. Currently Realm in version `2.3.1` for android.

Our android application already released in Playstore and many user using it. How to upgrade my realm db version without losing any data and functionalities.

I thought some `Realm` methods may be deprecated or removed from latest `Realm Db`

Comment: Have you tried to simple change lib version?

Comment: we are not tried to make any changes in realm

Comment: Just change the version and compare using your devices.

Comment: Actually, the latest version is 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Currently `Realm` db is in version `3.1.4` for `Android`. In order to migrate your database to the latest version,you have to change the `RealmConfiguration` code as follows

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                   .schemaVersion(1)
                   .migration(new MyMigration()) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
                   .build()
```

Assuming your schema is not changing, you also have to create the MyMigration class as follows,

```
public class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {
  @Override
   public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {
   }
}
```

You may refer to [Realm Docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) for more info